# Audioworklets and pitch

Tags: web-audio-api, audio-worklet

I've recently started working with audioworklets and am trying to figure out how to determine the pitch(s) from the input. I found a simple algorithm to use for a script processor, but the input values are different than a script processor and doesn't work. Plus each input array is only 128 units. So, how can I determine pitch using an audioworklet? As a bonus question, how do the values relate to the actual audio going in?

Answer (score 0):

If it worked with a ScriptProcessorNode, it will work in an AudioWorklet, but you'll have to buffer the data in the worklet because, as you noted, you only get 128 frames per call.  The ScriptProcessor gets anywhere from 256 to 16384.

The values going to the worklet are the actual values that are produced from the graph connected to the input.  These are exactly the same values that would go to the script processor, except you get them in chunks of 128.